Filtering dev environment events Google Analytics 4
I'm looking for a solution to be able to automatically filter pageviews from localhost. Ideally I'd like to track developer traffic but I'd like to not have to create custom reports manually to filter them.
GA4 currently gives 2 options to filter developer traffic:

Developer traffic (Filter events using debug_mode)
Internal traffic (IP Address range)

Option 2 wont work for me as I use multiple workstations at multiple locations.
Option 1 I'm a bit confused on. My understanding is if the debug_mode option in the gtag is set to true, the events will not be included in reports but can still be view in GA4>Admin>Data Display>DebugView? So should I just set debug_mode programmatically based on node env or domain (localhost) in my gtag?
I'm using react-ga4 which I'm not sure will work since I don't see the gtag debug_mode option mapped to any parameter for ReactGA.initialize(). But I also don't see it in the gtag options
docs either.
Regardless, same concept if I just have to implement the standard script provided by GA4.
    export const initGA = (ga4Id: string, devMode: boolean) => {
        ReactGA.initialize(ga4Id, {debug_mode: devMode});
    };

if (
    !window.GA_ANALYTICS &&
    googleAnalyticsTrackingCode
    ){
      
      if (apiHost.includes('localhost:'){
        initGA(googleAnalyticsTrackingCode, true);
      } else {
        initGA(googleAnalyticsTrackingCode, false);
      }

     window.GA_ANALYTICS = true;
}

Standard GA4 implementation
<Script src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.ga4}`}/>
<Script strategy="afterInteractive">
{`
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', '${process.env.ga4}', { 'debug_mode':${devMode} });
`}
</Script>

One other possible solution I saw is to create a custom variable and filter within GA4 described here Prevent Google Tag Manager from firing tag on localhost
Appreciate any insight to any methods anyone has used.

Well, the best thing to do would be to not use react-ga4 at all. It's not proper to have front-end framework working with behavioral analytics directly. There's a reason why we have tag management systems. They actually significantly reduce the load on the front-end by making it possible to delegate a large chunk of tracking to marketing folks.
But that would imply rewriting all your react-ga4 calls to dataLayer pushes and then setting up the logic in GTM to work with the dataLayer.
There's a faster fix in your case. No need for the debug mode. See where you have the ReactGA.initialize(ga4Id)? Use the production measurement id on prod and use the lower env measurement id on lowers. To do that, just go to GA4 and make another property. Indicate that it's for lowers. Use that property's data stream measurement id for the lowers. You actually don't need to do that, you can either use a random not existing measurement id or just suppress the whole tracking using some global debug flag, but it may be useful to be able to look at lower env traffic from time to time. And it's free, so why not.
How you determine whether it's a lower or prod is completely up to you, but it seems like checking the href should cover most of your concerns. But you also should have some reactish debug flag that indicates where we are.

I'm definitely considering separate property option. And definitely understand handing off analytic logic to marketing. My question then would be does the GA4 tag automatically log events, I would think developers would still need to add the event tracking options and set those up in GA4, no? And I'd still be curious how to use dev_mode since its not listed as an option in google dev docs, just a help article. thx!

also by 'reduce the load' did you mean application load or development work load?

I meant dev work load. App load is insignificant. Instead of including the package on the Node side, you'd be loading GTM on the front-end, from the DOM, as a third-party lib. Yes, devs would still need to push events into the window.dataLayer where GTM would be able to listen for them by overriding the .push() method, but then GTM has the ability to effectively eval JS to do whatever whoever wants to those events and translate them into any kinds of events without bothering the front-end. As for how to use debug in react-ga4, you already asked that in their issues, that's the best thing to do

One thing to know about the debug view is that it was not meant for filtering traffic out. The idea of it was to show full payloads of received debug events real time right in GA4's interface. But it's been so bugged that very few professional analytics people use it. It's notorious for misreporting real time events. Sometimes forgetting certain fields, sometimes reporting double events and sometimes losing events. The network tab is a lot more reliable.

Thanks for clarifying, that's what I assumed. Is the Filtering Developer Traffic google help article I linked to incorrect then?
"You can filter out activity from internal developers who use debug mode so developers can continue to use DebugView to troubleshoot issues while their activity doesn't appear in your reports."

no no, that's completely correct, it's just we're not using the debug flag for that. It's for analytics debugging and not to be on all the time on all lowers. In theory that would work, but given how unstable debug mode is, I wouldn't be surprised if it let things slip. It's just not the best practice to use it to seriously filter things out.
